# How do I remove only one instance from a list in Python?

Tags: python, list

So I have a Python script that reads in a .csv file of a play-by-play of a basketball game to calculate a plus/minus by lineup. It keeps track of the current players on the floor in a list of the player's last names, and I encounter an error when a team has two players with the same last name (the play-by-play data doesn't use first names, only numbers and last names, and I don't keep track of their numbers). The problem comes when I use lineup.remove(player) on one of the duplicate names, it removes both from the list. Is there an easy way to only remove one, and if so, can I specify which?

Example list would be

```
['JONES', 'PATTERSON', 'SMITH', 'JONES', 'WILLIAMS']
```

Comment: is the order important?

Comment: Not necessarily, but if there's a way to choose which one I'd like to do that. I suppose I could iterate through the list and check equality and use del or pop

Comment: Perhaps you *should* be using the player's numbers as their primary id instead of their non-unique names...!?

Comment: `list.remove(value)` removes only the first occurrence of `value`, not every occurrence. Are you calling `remove()` more than once? Can you show us your code?

Comment: I'm thinking I should just bite the bullet and add the players' numbers. @AndreaCorbellini I'm not calling remove more than once, and the code is in a 65 line loop, so I don't know if posting all of that will necessarily help. I just assumed it removed every instance, as I haven't had this problem with play-by-play data until one of the teams had two players with the same last name. I'll play around with the script more to see if I can pinpoint what's happening

Comment: Could you please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to debug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the docs:

list.remove(x)
Remove the first item from the list whose value is x. It is an error if there is no such item.

```
lineup = ['JONES', 'PATTERSON', 'SMITH', 'JONES', 'WILLIAMS']
lineup.remove('JONES') #should just remove the first occurrence of JONES
```

Comment: Thanks. I suppose it's another error popping up for who knows what reason. I just assumed it removed both because I hadn't had this problem until I had a play-by-play with two players with the same name.

Comment: perhaps consider adding the specific error message, the line which it's throwing the error and a printout of all variables referenced on that line

Answer (score 0):

```
list = ['JONES', 'PATTERSON', 'SMITH', 'JONES', 'WILLIAMS']
cleared_list = dict((x, 1) for x in list).keys()
```

This list doesn't keep the order, however.

This one keeps the order but it's slightly more complex:

```
list = ['JONES', 'PATTERSON', 'SMITH', 'JONES', 'WILLIAMS']

from itertools import count
seq = count()
d = {}
for x in list:
    d.setdefault(x, seq.next())
l = d.items();
l.sort(lambda x, y: cmp(x[1], y[1]))
cleared_list = [x[0] for x in l]
```